# Node JS array.includes not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have the following code which should filter one dynamic array (up to 300 thousand elements) from all elements not contained in another constant array:

```
orders[] //  is already filled with data
let materials = [] // create empty array
for (let scheme in schemes) { // loop constant object
    materials.push(schemes[scheme].typeID) // take id and add it to materials array
}
materials = Array.from(new Set(materials)) // filter out duplicates
console.log(materials) // everything looks fine here, 83 unique ids
for (let order in orders) { // now loop the main array
    if (!materials.includes(orders[order].type_id)) { // if order's containment id is not found in materials array
        orders.splice(order,1) // remove it from array
        order -= 1 // and one step back to compensate removed index (do I need it or is it processed normally even after .splice?) 
    }
}
// and send filtered orders into browser when a certain url is requested
```

However not all unnecessary records are filtered out. There are lots and lots of them whose IDs cannot  be found in materials array.

What is my mistake and where is the error?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: You know that Array lookup is O(n) and Set lookup is O(1)

Comment: .. and Never ever use `let scheme in schemes` to iterate over an array...

Comment: @str no it is not.

Comment: @JonasW. what's wrong with this iteration?

Comment: @JasonK how to apply .filter in my case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: @JonasW. seems like the wrong iteration method was the only problem in this code, everything works as it should now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (let scheme in schemes)
```

Thats how you iterate over keys in an object. Rather iterate over the entries in an array:

```
for (let scheme of schemes)
```

Additionally you should consider using the Set for lookup as its much faster. And `map` and `filter` might be useful:

```
const materials = new Set(schemes.map(scheme => scheme.typeID));

orders = orders.filter(el => materials.has(el.type_id));
```

Comment: That approach does work and it is lightning fast. 1 second against 1 minute of my original code.

Comment: @arctomachine glad to help :)