# javascript .includes method not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, stripe-payments

I am working with the stripe API to get a list of all used products in my subscriptions. I am going through all subscriptions and adding the used products into an array (or I'm trying to).

I only want to add a product if it has not been added in yet.

```
router.get('/getusedproducts', asyncHandler(async(req,res,next) => {
  var products = [];
  for await (const subscription of stripe.subscriptions.list()) {
    for (i = 0; i < subscription.items.data.length; i++) {
      var prod = subscription.items.data[i].plan.product;
      if (!products.includes[prod]){
        products.push(prod)
        console.log(prod);
      }
    }
  }
  res.send(products)
}));
```

Currently, this piece of code isn't working as intended because I am still seeing the console log all product. Ideally, the check `!products.includes[prod]` should prevent that, but it isn't. I've read several discussion here on stack ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378228/check-if-an-element-is-present-in-an-array))([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364383/if-an-element-already-exists-in-an-array-dont-add-it-again/41364474))([3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175939/node-js-array-includes-not-working-as-expected))

Not sure exactly how to compare the items in the array to the new ones I'm getting from JSON object to check if exists.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `!products.includes(prod)` not `!products.includes[prod]`, `.includes` is function

Comment: Why would that not throw an error? Is that just a JS quirk? I'd expect that to just not work if I used incorrect syntax there... @ponury-kostek

Comment: Because `.includes` exists and you can access it's properties with `[prod]`

Answer (score 0):

includes is method so has to be used like `somArray.includes(value).`

Please be aware that includes method is not supported in IE or Edge<14. If you are not targeting IE/Edge<14 then no issues there. Otherwise, use the good old indexOf method to look for elements in array.